# Béchamel and pomodoro

Tags: sauce, pasta, bechamel, hot-sauce

Is there any traditional recipe that uses béchamel (white sauce) and pomodoro (tomato sauce) mixed, making a new (*orange-ish*) sauce?

Is there a name for this sauce?

I often do this mixture but I've never seen it in any recipe.

Comment: I think more traditional approaches would just be to add cream to the tomato sauce... or a soft fresh cheese like mozzarella.  This creates what Italian American's call a "pink sauce."

Comment: Tomato cream sauce with basil is rather close, but simpler; it's simply concentrated tomato paste, butter, cream, maybe garlic, and salt and pepper to taste. Fresh basil as garnish.

Comment: I've seen lasagna recipes that use a bechamel and tomato sauce, but they're layered, not mixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I am uncertain about Italian cookery, this operation would seem fairly unorthodox in the French repertoire. That being said, it is customary to add cream, salt pork or bacon, and flour to *sauce tomate*, which essentially replicates the addition of *Bechamel*, although it seems Escoffier deigned not to include cream in his recipe for this mother sauce.

Perusing the section of compound white sauces in Escoffier's *Guide Culinaire*, there are several sauces that are at least *similar* to that which you described,

. *Sauce Aurore* - A *Veloute* to which tomato puree is added; for eggs, meat, and poultry

. *Sauce Soubise Tomatee* - A *soubise* is a sauce with onions that may have *bechamel* as a base

. *Sauce Villeroy Tomatee* - An *Allemande* to which tomato puree is added

Now I would suggest simply calling what you described *"Sauce Tomate a la Creme"* and not be discouraged to not find its exact replica in the canons of classical cuisine.

Answer (score 5):

In Italy we usually mix béchamel and tomato sauce for "Pasta al forno" (or "[pasta pasticciata](http://www.gustissimo.it/ricette/pasta-carne/pasta-pasticciata.htm)") and lasagna, in order to not have a full distinction in the final dish between the two sauces and their tastes.

However this is not mandatory, but my grandma, my mum and me are used to do it (and I see some other people doing the same).

*P.s.*
I live in Italy and I'm 100% italian :-)

Comment: I don't live in Italy but I've recently started doing this and it's delicious, especially with a little left-over pieces of cheese whisked in.